# Google Cloud Storage Client not working on dev appserver

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, dev-appserver

I 'm building an AppEngine application that stores data in Google Cloud Storage. I use the Google Cloud Storage Client (GCS) library as suggested.

My app is working when deployed on AppEngine (reading/writing/listing objects) but I cannot make it work on the development server. The development server keeps returning error 404 and GCS raises NotFoundError. The dev-appserver is supposed to emulate the cloud storage functionality without any specific configurations etc. I see in the log files that the dev server is accepting requests at "/_ah/gcs" yet it seems that there is no handler for that url. I 've tried with version 1.8.5 and 1.8.6. Apart from my app, not even the demo app provided by Google works.

Is there something that I 'm missing here, e.g. a special configuration for the dev-appserver?

Comment: Exactly the same problem here. Is it possible this was recently broken? A [checkin to appengine-gcs-client dated 10/29/13](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-gcs-client/source/detail?r=125) seems to have introduced the `/_ah/gcs` endpoint. Is the client out of sync with dev appserver?

Comment: That's so annoying. In fact, a lot of the PHP runtime is so broken and inconsistent. Arrrg... On my dev box I'm handling the GCS described by special casing uploads to dev environment by uploading to some local dir... Ugly, but works for now.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry the following change was pushed out too early by mistake. It only works with 1.8.8 SDK. We are streamlining the release process of gcs client to align with SDK. Sorry

https://code.google.com/p/appengine-gcs-client/source/detail?r=125
Without this change, it works on 1.8.7 SDK.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but given so you said, what do we do to get it working again?

Comment: You can either sync from SVN revision 124. Or go to https://code.google.com/p/appengine-gcs-client/
and download the zip entitled "appengine-gcs-client-python-r124.zip"

Comment: Just to report it works with GAE SDK 1.8.8 and latest gcs (hadn't tried with 1.8.7)

Comment: Hey Yey, I'm using 1.8.8 and installed google cloud storage r124 & 126 by dropping it into the main folder of my app. First time user, and I can't access the /_ah/gcs folder either. "INFO:root:default: "GET /_ah/gcs HTTP/1.1" 404 154"

Comment: Running into the same issue with the latest Google Cloud SDK 114.0.0... /_ah/gcs paths can't be loaded, but on the server it works, can anyone confirm?